# How to edit a native build system in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Ok this is very trivial question, but just cannot find answer anywhere.

I know there must be a JSON file with all the build systems somewhere, but I just cannot find it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Here is the doc on ST2 build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)

The Ruby build file, for instance, is located here:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build`

Comment: You shouldn't edit the default, but instead make a copy in your User preferences. This will supersede the default, and be retained as you upgrade Sublime.

Comment: but what should I doing with long list unnecessary default build systems?

Comment: **See:** [**This Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37177400/4955183) for an easy way to edit default files without overwriting them. ( *as mentioned in the first comment on this answer* )

Answer (score 12):

Mac:

`Preferences ► Browse Packages` will open the finder window where all the `foo.sublime-build` files are stored.

Build sys scripts you have created yourself should be in:

`/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/`

Answer (score 3):

As dbw said, basically you should make a copy of default setting file to your User folder and edit it to override default one. And on ST3 most default setting files are packaged, use PackageResourceView will make your work easier.

For example edit default ST3 python buid setting on Windows:

- **ctrl+alt+p**, type "**prv**" and select "**open**" to call PackageResourceView's open.
- select "**python**" > "**Python.sublime-build**"
- notice default file path is "...\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build", so create a user copy to Users "\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build" and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In sublime use this step

> Tools -> Build System -> New Build System

Than a new build file will be opened . On saving this file , sublime will prompt the ***file dialogue option*** to save the file . Than you can see the ***location*** where sublime saves all the native build files . From this location you can edit the existing native build files .

Comment: not really, that only opens a directory where all user defined stuff saved