# Where do some sublime packages and default settings go?

Tags: sublimetext3

Sometimes I install a new sublime package and a new directory gets added to the `/Users/max/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` directory, which I like because I can use a bookmark with [FuzzyFileNav](https://github.com/facelessuser/FuzzyFileNav/blob/master/docs/usage.md#suggested-accessibility-shortcuts) and quickly browse the default `.sublime-settings` and `.sublime-key` files to get my bearings about what is going on with this package. However sometimes there is no entry added, as shown below (ironically with FuzzyFileNav) 
[image]

So then the way I would find the `.sublime-settings` and `.sublime-keymap` files is to use the dropdown menu in sublime also shown below:

[image]

What I'm wondering is:

1. Why do some packages add entries to my Packages directory and other don't?
2. If there is no entry in Packages then where do the package specific `.sublime-settings` and `.sublime-keymap` files live?

My main goal is to be able to quickly navigate between my User and Default settings but it makes it hard when I'm feeling like Hansel and wondering where'd all the files go...you know :)

One workaround that might work is to copy all the Default `.sublime-settings` and `.sublime-keymap` files that don't live in the Packages directory and put them in the User directory and rename them to `PackageName.sublime-settings` and `PackageName.sublime-keymap` and then I'll be able to browse them anyways because I also have a bookmark to User. I think that would work because it would overwrite all the Default settings (that live somewhere) with all the exact same settings. Or maybe I could do that same thing except put the files in the Default directory; however, from what I've been reading it's bad form to modify the Default directory. Obviously the most ideal thing would be to just figure out where the heck these files are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime Text uses different folder locations for different kinds of packages. For instance, all packaged files install to `Installed Packages` and are self-contained in a standard Zip file using the file extension `.sublime-package`. When a package includes a file `.no-sublime-package`, the package will be extracted. All extracted packages are stored in the `Packages` folder.

Settings and keymaps are stored within both packed and unpacked packages. Those can be overruled/extended by saving them to `Packages/User`.

Detailed information on package locations and hierarchy can be found in the [Package Control documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/customizing_packages).

Comment: idleberg, thanks for that. So if I'm understanding the documentation correctly one way I could get a more uniform setup would be to:

Comment: 1. Create a new entry name PackageName inside `Packages` every time I install a package that does not have a .no-sublime-package file (which is the reason why sublime wouldn't put the PackageName directory there in the first place) and create two files in that directory PackageName.sublime-settings and PackageName.sublime-keymap

Comment: 2. Navigate to the `PackageName.sublime-settings` and `PackageName.sublime-keymap` files by using the dropdown sublime menu and copy and paste the contents into the newly created files that are inside `Packages`

Comment: 3. Now we're back to "normal" to edit either the settings or keymap I can create an entry PackageName.sublime-settings and put it in my User directory or I can edit the `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file, also in my User directory

Comment: @mbigras: For `sublime-settings`, make sure that it exists and that you match the existing name ( *Technically, the settings file does not need to match the package name, although most of the time it will. It is also possible for a package to have multiple settings files.* ). The `sublime-keymap` should be `Default.sublime-keymap` or `Default (Your OS).sublime-keymap` if the package dev utilized OS specific key bindings. The three options are `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap`, `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`, & `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`.

Comment: Enteleform, are you saying that packages will only honor settings in the `Default****.sublime-keymap

Answer (score 3):

[**idleberg's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168258/4955183) contains a good explanation of *why* you were unable to find `.sublime-package` files & unpackaged files in the same location.

The following information details an alternative method you can use to navigate *all* package files, whether packed or unpacked.

---

All of SublimeTexst's installed package files can be navigated and edited via [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)'s `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` command.

Any files that are edited from a `.sublime-package` file will have a new instance created at `Packages/PackageName`.  The new file will now override the original file ( *which still exists in the* `.sublime-package` *file* ). The original file can be reactivated by deleting the edited file.

Files edited from an unpacked package will be affected directly.

If both packaged & unpackaged instances of a file exist, `PackageResourceViewer` will open the unpackaged instance.

Comment: +1 for suggesting such a rad plugin. I actually already use it and I think it's awesome; however, I was wondering if it will be okay for me to use the procedure mentioned in the comments of idleberg's post because I like working with FuzzyFileNav more than PackageResourceViewer and I have a bookmark to both the User and Default directories. Based off the documentation it seems like it will be okay, but some of my efforts may be overwritten later in the Default directory.